# Java Spring: Jackson deserialization to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring, parsing, jackson, zoneddatetime

Assuming the following class I want to use for deserialization from an external JSON payload:

```
public class MyObject {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    private ZonedDateTime timestamp;

}
```

When I'm trying to consume the JSON payload, Jackson throws the following error:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` from String "2019-01-23T12:54:18.610Z": Failed to deserialize java.time.ZonedDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019-01-23T12:54:18.610Z' could not be parsed at index 23
```

As you can see, the incoming string is `"2019-01-23T12:54:18.610Z"`, which is a valid ZonedDateTime as I understand it. Using jshell, parsing that string into a ZonedDateTime using `ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-01-23T12:54:18.610Z")` results in a valid ZonedDateTime as I would expect.

- Why is Jackson failing here?
- What can I do to make it work?

I'm not an expert on Spring or Jackson, either. Thanks.

Edit: I'm using Spring Boot v2.1.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date String in Java [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Z in the pattern won't accept a literal 'Z' in the value, using X instead should work:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX")
```

The pattern is specified as a Java `SimpleDateFormat` - Java 10 reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

You shoud replace `Z` with `X`, like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```